# How do I get rid of the "Project" tab on top of treeview in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I recently switched to a Mac, and when downloading Atom I noticed something odd. Instead of the normal treeview sidebar that was on my old PC, it seems to be under a tab named "Project" now. I can't seem to make it go away. Is there a way to do this without hiding the treeview itself? Is this just a Mac-specific feature?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQdVb.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a change in Atom 1.17, which was released recently. Instead of only panes, like before, Atom now has "docks". The tree view is implemented as a dock.

Since docks may have more than one child pane, they use tabs, just like the editor panes do. You are seeing the tab for the tree-view pane.

If you were to update the PC version of Atom to 1.17, you would see the same thing.

[This blog post](http://blog.atom.io/2017/05/16/atom-1-17.html) discusses the new docks feature.